# Why is the Australian Labor Party spelt without a 'u'?

Tags: australian-english

In both the UK and New Zealand there are Labour parties spelt with a u.

[The Labour Party.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labour_Party_%28UK%29)

[The New Zealand Labour Party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zealand_Labour_Party)

In Australia, it's The *Labor* Party.

[Australian Labor Party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Labor_Party)

What explains this discrepancy? Given that all three have similar spellings for everything else (eg. 'colour', 'realise').

Comment: Remember that Australia is in the southern hemisphere, so an awful lot of things appear upside down and a bit strange.

Comment: The answer was in the same Wiki link you provided :) there's even a menu saying ["name changes"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Labor_Party#Name_changes)

Comment: "[T]he American-born King O'Malley, was successful in having the spelling 'modernised'." It's amusing to think of an American-born Australian insisting on changing _labour_ to _labor_ in the name of "modernising" (rather than modernizing) the country's orthography.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Australian spelling of labour is just like the BrE one. The reason why labour is spelled labor in *Australian Labor  Party* is an important historical one:

[Australian  ***Labor***  Party](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Labor_Party#Name_changes):

> - The ALP adopted the formal name "Australian Labour Party" ***in 1908, but changed the spelling to "Labor" in 1912. While it is standard practice in Australian English both today and at the time to spell the word "labour" with a "u", the party was influenced by the United States labor movement***, and ***a prominent figure in the early history of the party, the American-born King O'Malley, was successful in having the spelling "modernised"***.
> - The change also made it easier to distinguish references to the party from the labour movement in general.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: God that must be grating to literate Australians.

Comment: @dwjohnston the worst part is when you accidentally spell it "correctly" and then people take pride in telling you "It doesn't have a U in it, you know..."

Comment: @aaa90210 in that case the question would be "Why is it called L4bor?". What's your point?

Comment: @MarkHenderson are you slow or something? The point is names don't have to follow normal English rules, and can contain incorrect spellings, like the incorrect spelling of Labor (under Australian English), or L4bor as it would be.

Comment: "American-born King O'Malley" now there is a contentious issue, [O'Malley insisted he was born in Canada!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_O%27Malley)

Answer (score -3):

The "Australian Labor Party" is a **name** (note the capitalized L). Names don't have to follow language rules, much like the name of the airline QANTAS does not have a U after the Q.

> Given that all three have similar spellings for everything else (eg. 'colour', 'realise').

You can add "labour" to that list. That is how the word "labour" is spelt in Australia. Even members of the Labor Party spell "labour" as "labour". How they write the **name** of their party has nothing to do with the general use of the word "labour".

Spelling of words in general have nothing to do with spelling of names and trademarks. Does that help break your confusion?

Comment: QANTAS is an acronym. Labor is not.

Comment: @MarkHenderson you are wrong, QANTAS is NOT an acronym, the airline is not known as the "Queensland and Northern Territory air service". Maybe you are stuck in the 1920's when it was last known as so. Your point is also irrelevant, as names, trademarks, acronymns all don't need to follow standard English rules.

Comment: Not sure if trolling or just... nevermind

Comment: +1 for the whole post, but esp *Even members of the Labor Party spell "labour" as "labour".* Love this line!

Answer (score -7):

It is the English UK spelling. Most british colonized countries would use this spelling.

Just to let you know.. Its not wierd, the world doesn't run on American spelling :) Just like most of the world uses the metric system, unlike America.

Comment: This is, y'know, wrong. The BrE spelling (and the Australian spelling) is "Labour."

Comment: Ivan, I think you may have misread the title. It says **without** a "U".

Comment: The American spelling of "wierd" is "weird". (And sometimes we spell "its" with an apostrophe.)